# Recording mp3 on iPhone by SDK

Tags: iphone, xcode, audio, mp3, audio-recording

I'm wondering if it's possible to record an audio file in mp3 format programmatically with Xcode.

I've read a tons of documentations and I've googled for this, but no result.

Please help, if someone knows how this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start here

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_AudioVideo_iPhone/_index.html,

try to record some raw sound file and then convert it to mp3 with some 3rd party library like LAME.
You can pick up LAME source here:

http://lame.sourceforge.net/

Try building a static library for iOS / armv6, I actually managed to build it couple of minutes ago, but I'm too tired to try if it actually works :) There is probably no easy way to do this, hope this helps in your search. I will try LAME in the next couple of days and let you know however.

Answer (score 2):

The iPhone SDK doesn't support MP3 encoding. It does support hardware AAC/m4a encoding which is in many ways superior to mp3.

Answer (score 1):

AAC/m4a hardware encoding is supported starting in iOS 3.1 for iPhone 3GS and iPod touch (2nd generation) and in iOS 3.2 for iPad.

Take a look here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/UsingAudio/UsingAudio.html