# Android audio recording issue with MediaRecorder OutputFormat AAC_ADTS

Tags: android, android-audiorecord

I am trying to record an audio from my android app. Everything worked well. Recently, I had to change the output format from MPEG4 to AAC_ADTS. The issue is that AAC_ADTS does not work for one of the device It works on the other device. So, my question is does AAC_ADTS format work only on certain android versions. How can I get the audio recorded in AAC_ADTS format from all devices? Kindly help

```
mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AAC_ADTS);
//        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
//        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);

        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AAC_ADTS format is added in API level 16, and works only on android versions 4.1+.
See this link below.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.html

Comment: ok thanks. Any idea which is the best format to use so that the recorded audio would work across devices also on other platforms like windows, ios etc.

Comment: I have 19 (4.4) at it still fails to record this format